# Dynamic parameters in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function in which append method is taking a static parameter.

```
 function toggle() {
         $("#MS").append($('#hide'));        
    }
```

What i want is to pass the parameter dynamically from my Hyperlinks click event.
In above code that #MS is static which i want to pass dynamically

Code:
HTML

```
<div id="MS">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggle();">JP MORGAN</a><br>
    </div>
```

I want to pass the argument from onclick to toggle method and that parameter will be used in the append method.

I have tried several combinations buut it didnt worked.
Please help..

My new code after changes

```
<script>
$(function() { // when the DOM is ready
    var $hide = $('#hide').click(function(){
       $(this).closest('div').hide();
    }); 

    $('a.toggle').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).parent().append($hide);
    });
}); 


</script>

<div id="JP">
        <a href="#">JP MORGAN</a><br>       
    </div>
```

still not working

Comment: But you haven't added classes to your `a` elements! `<a href="#" class="toggle">JP MORGAN</a><br>       `

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/keEDH/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, you can add classes to your `a` elements and use `parent` method:

```
$(function() { // when the DOM is ready
    var $hide = $('#hide').click(function(){
       $(this).closest('div').hide();
    }); 

    $('a.toggle').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).parent().append($hide);
    });
});
```

Comment: @Azuu In a script tag or a `js` file!

Comment: i put the cod ein the script tag and called the function like this onclick="toggle();" but its not working

Comment: what should i put inside href..?

Comment: @Azuu You don't need that function, you can remove the function and `onclick` attribute. jQuery `click` method handle this.

Comment: 1 more question i am having a table which i am appending to different hrefs but i want the table to be hidden bydefault then onclick it should be visible

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the `ID` dynamically on the anchor's `click` event and pass that ID to the function:

```
$("a").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).append($('#hide')); 

};
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting an invalid markup? IDs must be unique.

Comment: Every time you write any variation of `$("#"+$(this).attr("id"))`, a lolcat dies a horrible death.

Comment: @undefined where are the duplicated IDs then?

Comment: @VeXii The ID of clicked element is used for selecting another element?

Comment: @undefined Am I missing something? The id's would be unique in the original `html` markup. When an a tag is clicked, it would select that specific anchor and append whatever he wants to append to it.